# ngMaterialDateRangePicker não atualiza o modelo

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Estou tentando utilizar date range picker do ngMaterial, mas sem sucesso.. .por algum motivo ele não está atualizando o model.
Fiz a chamada no JS:

```
angular.module('events-create',
    [
        'ngMaterial',
        'ngAria',
        'ngMaterialDateRangePicker'
    ])
```

E, no html:

```
<md-date-range
    ng-model="vm.model.startsAt"
    auto-confirm="true"
    show-template="false"
    one-panel="true">
 </md-date-range>
```

vm.model.startsAt fica aparecendo como null pra mim.

AngularJs 1.5.11

Alguma idéia? (se tiver alguma ideia de como detalhar melhor a pergunta, tb aceito.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Precisava declarar o modelo do campo que vai receber o calendário como objeto, para que, selecionando as datas, o modelo seja atualizado.